# How to display image in desktop as ipad image?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I was wondering if it is possible to display images in desktop the way it shows in iPad?

I am building a web application and let the user creates the images, but it needs to be displayed properly in iPad or iPhone. Is there a way to simulate the way iPad would show in the desktop webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a PC, there is no way I am aware of. On Mac, you could install Xcode, which is meant for developers but comes with a free iPad simulator. By launching Xcode, creating a project with some dummy details, hitting run in the top left (make sure the iPad option is selected), you have an iPad simulator. You may need to get out of the app being simulator by going to Hardware>Home. You can swipe over to safari and use it as if it is on an iPad. Let me know if you need some clarification.